# Haar measure on 2 by 2 upper right matrices

Tags: matrices, measure-theory, haar-measure

Let $G$ be $
    \left(
    \begin{matrix}
    a & b \\
    0 & 1
    \end{matrix}    \right)$, which is a group endowed with matrix multiplication (This has been already shown). Suppose that we identify $G$ with the right-half plane in $\mathbb{R}^2$ by associating the point $(a,b)$ to the matrix $
    \left(
    \begin{matrix}
    a & b \\
    0 & 1
    \end{matrix}    \right)$.

Show that the formula

$$\mu(A)=\int\int_A \frac{1}{a^2}dadb$$

defines a left Haar measure on $G$, and that the formula 
        $$\mu(A)=\int\int_A \frac{1}{a}dadb$$

defines a right Haar measure on $G$

$\textbf{This is my approach}$

First, let us consider the left Haar measure. A left translation by $u=(x,y)$ is given by:
$$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
x & y \\
0 & 1
\end{matrix}    \right)
\left(
\begin{matrix}
a & b \\
0 & 1
\end{matrix}    \right)=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
xa & xb+y \\
0 & 1
\end{matrix}    \right)$$

Then $da$ becomes $xda$, $db$ becomes $xdb$, and $a$ becomes $xa$. Therefore
$$\mu(uA)=\int\int_{uA}\dfrac{1}{a^2}dadb=\int\int_A\dfrac{1}{(ax)^{2}}xdaxdb=\int\int_A\dfrac{1}{a^2}dadb=\mu(A) $$

Now, let us consider the right Haar measure. A right translation by $u=(x,y)$ is given by: 
$$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
a & b \\
0 & 1
\end{matrix}    \right)
\left(
\begin{matrix}
x & y \\
0 & 1
\end{matrix}    \right)=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
xa & ya+b \\
0 & 1
\end{matrix}    \right)$$

Then $da$ becomes $xda$, $db$ becomes $db$, and $a$ becomes $xa$. Therefore

$$\mu(Au)=\int\int_{Au}\dfrac{1}{a}dadb=\int\int_A\dfrac{1}{ax}xdadb=\int\int_A\dfrac{1}{a}dadb=\mu(A)$$

Is this enough to answer the question? and more importantly, is this correct? I'd appreciate if anyone can check my procedure.